# Как десерилизовать поле в jackson?

Tags: kotlin, jackson, десериализация

В ответе в поле может прийти пустой список или объект, как десерилизовать?

Так работает если объект и ошибка когда пустой список и наоборот если сделать списком!

```
data class Test(
    val meta: Meta?,

) {
    data class Meta(
        val timeout: Int,
    )
}
```

Comment: Свой десериализатор написать? https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Comment: написал свой, нашел еще обходной путь, может кому пригодится
```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "success")
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Test.SuccessSms::class, name = "true"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Test.ErrorSms::class, name = "false"),
)
```